# Problems with as.numeric

Tags: r

i have a vector of characters

```
UTM.X
  [1] "565,144.03" "565,144.05" "565,144.11"
```

i do the following to remove the commas

```
as.character(lapply(strsplit(UTM.X,","),function(x) paste(x,collapse="")))
  [1] "565144.03" "565144.05" "565144.11"
```

Then try to change them to numbers

```
as.numeric(as.character(lapply(strsplit(UTM.X,","),function(x) paste(x,collapse=""))))
  [1] 565144.0300000000279397 565144.0500000000465661 565144.1099999999860302
```

So where do the extra trailing decimals come from. i would understand if they were zeros but this is really confusing me. I have done this may times but this baffles me.

Reduction the digits with options(digits=13) from my original digits=22 hides the decimals but doesnt explain why they are there. i also noticed that with a longer vector the end decimals are somewhat the same numbers, i.e either 00000000279397,  99999999860302 or 00000000465661

Comment: `as.numeric(c("565144.03","565144.05","565144.11"))` gives me `[1] 565144.0 565144.1 565144.1`. there are differences in the way r (and your pc) store and print numbers. check your `options('digits')`

Comment: After reading your data with `scan(...,sep=" ",what="character")` it works for me without causing the large numbers of digits after the commas

Comment: This is the well-known (or at least we used to think so until this question showed up a zillion times on SO :-( ) effect of converting floating-point numbers into binary representation and back.